# Redirect during specific date range

Tags: conditionals, date-format

I have 2 conditionals at the beginning of a template that are supposed to redirect the visitor to a different template if they are hitting the page outside of 2 different time spans, but the redirect is not working.

```
{if '{current_time format="%U"}' < '{start_date_1}' AND '{current_time format="%U"}' > '{end_date_1}'}{redirect="/closed"}{/if}
{if '{current_time format="%U"}' < '{start_date_2}' AND '{current_time format="%U"}' > '{end_date_2}'}{redirect="/closed"}{/if}
```

{start_date_1}, {start_date_2}, {end_date_1} & {end_date_2} are global variables.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are the start date global variables in the same format as you're setting the current_time variables?

Comment: Yes, they are. I've even tried replacing the variables with the actual date values and it still doesn't work.

Comment: can you share the start date global variable value? As `{current_time format="%U"}` will be UNIX time so start_date_x and end_date_x should be in same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your conditional doesn't make any sense. It's impossible for a number to be less and greater than an interval at the same time.

You need a `OR`, not an `AND`.

```
{if '{current_time format="%U"}' < '{start_date_1}' OR '{current_time format="%U"}' > '{end_date_1}'}{redirect="/closed"}{/if}
{if '{current_time format="%U"}' < '{start_date_2}' OR '{current_time format="%U"}' > '{end_date_2}'}{redirect="/closed"}{/if}
```

Comment: Duh. That was it! So obvious yet had me going in circles. Thanks!